# Using MonadRandom with MonadState

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, algebraic-data-types, state-monad

I have this bit of code:

```
import Data.Random
import Control.Monad.State

foo :: s -> StateT s RVar ()
foo s = do
  p <- lift $ (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double)
  if p > 0.5 then put s else return ()
```

And I would like to refactor its signature to be of form:

```
foo :: (MonadState s m, RandomSource m s) => s -> m ()
```

I thought I could equip `RVar` with `MonadState` functions:

```
{- LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (RVarT m) where
  get   = lift get
  put   = lift . put
  state = lift . state
```

and write:

```
foo :: (MonadState s m, RandomSource m s) => s -> m ()
foo s = do
  p <- (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double)
  if p > 0.5 then put s else return ()
```

But I am getting this inexplicable error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘m’
                   with ‘t0 (RVarT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            foo :: (MonadState s m, RandomSource m s) => s -> m ()
          at ApproxMedian.hs:99:8
    Expected type: m Double
      Actual type: t0 (RVarT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity) Double
    Relevant bindings include
      foo :: s -> m () (bound at ApproxMedian.hs:100:1)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: p <- lift $ (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double)
    In the expression:
      do { p <- lift $ (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double);
           if p > 0.5 then put s else return () }
    In an equation for ‘foo’:
        foo s
          = do { p <- lift $ (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double);
                 if p > 0.5 then put s else return () }
Failed, modules loaded: Core, Statistics.
```

1. Please explain the error and help make the more generic signature possible?
2. If I wanted to do:

   ```
   foo :: (MonadRandom m, MonadState s m) => s -> m ()
   ```

How would I implement it?  I cannot use `uniform` any more. Because it locks me to signature `RVar a` but I really want `MonadRandom m => m a`, 
or at the very least `Monad m => RVarT m a`

Comment: You wrote `(uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double)` but you declared the type of the function to be `m ()`. The monads must match - `m` must be equal to `RVar`, which it is not. You may *not* use the signature `(MonadRandom m, MonadState s m) => s -> m ()` in particular because the `uniform` function is implemented for RVar, not for any MonadRandom.

Comment: You can have `MonadState s m => s -> RVarT m ()`, of course, simply use `uniformT :: Distribution Uniform a => a -> a -> RVarT m a`.

Answer (score 3):

`uniform` is not polymorphic in the monad it runs in (in other words, you can't run it in any choice of `m` if all you know is that `RandomSource m s`):

```
uniform :: Distribution Uniform a => a -> a -> RVar a
```

However, if you have a source of entropy, you can `runRVar` it in any `m` if `RandomSource m s`:

```
runRVar :: RandomSource m s => RVar a -> s -> m a
```

which means you can write `foo` with your desired type signature as

```
foo :: (MonadState s m, RandomSource m s) => s -> m ()
foo s = do
  p <- runRVar (uniform 0 1 :: RVar Double) s
  when (p > 0.5) $ put s
```